# Eclipse PDE: How to load a new project in Package Explorer programmatically?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have developed an Eclipse plugin that creates a new custom project via project creation wizard using INewWizard.

[image]

Once user inputs information and clicks 'Finish', project gets created within workspace successfully. Issue is that Package Explorer doesn't load this newly created project upon 'Finish' event. What should be implemented under performFinish() of the final wizard page to load the project in Package Explorer automatically?

How to load such newly created project in Package Explorer programmatically?

Comment: I came across updatePerspective() method but no clue on how to use it.

Comment: Are you using `IProject.create` and the other `IFile` APIs? Using the correct APIs the project should be picked up automatically.

Comment: @greg-449 Actually neither way... I've created a custom template (Simple C++ project with few additional libraries) on file system and copying it to workspace on performFinish(). I couldn't find 'working' way to create C++ project programmatically. Would be great if you could point to right steps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally a project should be created using the version of `IProject.create` which takes a `IProjectDescriptor`. But if you are creating the project files some other way you still need to create the project using `IProject` to tell Eclipse about it. You can use something like:

```
IWorkspaceRoot root = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
IProject project = root.getProject(projectName);
if (!project.exists()) {
    project.create(monitor);
} else {
    project.refreshLocal(IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE, monitor);
}

// TODO add files

project.refreshLocal(IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE, monitor);
```

Comment: Thanks! Above code successfully creates and automatically renders the project directory in Project Explorer. One issue: I still have to right-click project directory and select 'Open Project' to render 'Includes' section. Is there any way to automate this scenario. This is purely a C++ project with few additional libraries.